# Log message to database whenever an email arrives

Tags: command-line, scripts, log, database

Does anyone have a script that will log a message to a database anytime an email arrives? I'm referring to a native imap server running on ubuntu. I'd like to log a message anytime any email arrives on any account.

Comment: I imagine the answers would depend on which email server you are using. Personally I'm using `gmail.com`.

Comment: Excellent point. I'm referring to a native imap server running on ubuntu...

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: You are confused. IMAP does not handle incoming mail; the MTA (*e.g.*, Postfix) does.